# *As* he finished his speech, the audience

Tags: grammar

**As** he finished his speech, the audience burst into applause.

Doesn't "as" suggest the two actions happened simultaneously? But they could not happen simultaneously. The audience applauded as soon as he finished hi speech. There is a sequence of actions. So I think "when" works and "as" does not.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

' AS ' when used as a conjunction goes to mean amongst others, ' at the time that' ; 'during the time when'; ' while' ;  'with the result that it is' according to Wiktionary. To illustrate it gives the example that corroborates your example:

As I came in, she fled.

So " as" exactly serves the function of " when " , and there is nothing wrong whatsoever.

Comment: "As I came in, she fled" means differently from "When I came in, she fled".

Answer (score 1):

Just like you've said, in this case **as** is used when two events are happening simultaneously. The audience might have started laughing as he was uttering his last words of the joke, or even at the time when he finished the joke. I don't see any problem with the sentence.

Comment: What if I use "when"? Does it have a little different meaning?

Comment: Yes, the meaning changes a little.   "When he finished his speech, the audience burst into applause." implies that the audiences started laughing after he finished his speech.